# determining whether numbers can be written as polynomials in terms of each other

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Given two radical expressions, $a$ and $b$, I have an algorithm that finds a polynomial $P(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $a=P(b)$, if one exists. If not, I can also find a radical expression $c$ such that $a$ and $b$ can both be written as polynomials in $c$. Is it possible to use these algorithms to determine whether, given radical expressions $a$ and $b_1,...,b_n$, there is a polynomial $P(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{Q}[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that $a=P(b_1,...,b_n)$?

The algorithms I refer to are both applications of algorithm 4.5.4 in [this book](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/A%20course%20in%20computational%20algebraic%20number%20theory%20-%20Cohen.pdf). The first is the field membership problem, as described on page 179, and the second, the primitive element problem, as described on page 181. My ultimate goal is, given any radical expression, to find an equivalent expression that is a polynomial in terms of some expression $a$ where, if $a$ has multiple terms, none of the terms are polynomials in terms of any of the others.

By "radical expressions" I mean elements of the smallest set $S\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that

1. $\mathbb{Q}\subset S$
2. If $a,b\in S$ then $a+b,a-b,a*b\in S$
3. If $a,b\in S$ and $b\neq 0$ then $a/b\in S$
4. If $a\in S$, $b\in\mathbb{Q}$, and $a,b$ are not both $0$ then $a^b\in S$

This is, I believe, the subset of algebraic numbers that are roots of polynomials that are said to be "solvable."

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb Q[x]$ and $\mathbb Q[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$?  Round brackets here generally mean rational expressions rather than polynomials.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh, yes I do.

Comment: What do you mean by "radical expressions"?

Comment: Alex, do you really have such an algorithm or are you discussing a hypothetical situation?

Comment: For example, I use algdep in Pari, which uses LLL to find a polynomial with integer coefficients for which the target number is very close to being a root. Your algorithm seems much more ambitious.

Comment: @WillJagy I do. At least, I'm pretty sure I do. I can always find the minimal polynomial of a radical expression (which I could go into if you really want, but it's complicated), and given that, I can use algorithm 4.5.4 from this book: http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/A%20course%20in%20computational%20algebraic%20number%20theory%20-%20Cohen.pdf

Comment: Alex, put some of that in the question. Cohen's book(s) is(are) well known, it will help fix notation if you talk about it.

Comment: @Somos I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is $P(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{Q[x_1,...,x_n]}$ such that $a=P(b_1,...,b_n)$. Let $c_1=b_1$, let $R_1(x)=x$, let $c_i$ be the result of applying the second algorithm to $c_{i-1}$ and $b_i$, and let $Q_{i-1}(x)$ and $R_i(x)$ be the polynomials such that $c_{i-1}=Q_{i-1}(c_i)$ and $b_i=R_i(c_i)$. Let $\Phi_0(x)=x$ and $\Phi_i(x)=Q_{n-i}(\Phi_{i-1}(x))$ so that $\Phi_{n-i}(c_n)=c_i$, and let
$$\Psi(x)=P(R_1(\Phi_{n-1}(x)),...,R_n(\Phi_0(x)))$$
Then
$$\Psi(c_n)=P(R_1(\Phi_{n-1}(c_n)),...,R_n(\Phi_0(c_n)))=P(R_1(c_1),...,R_n(c_n))=P(b_1,...,b_n)=a$$
Thus there is a polynomial in $c_n$ that equals $a$, and the first algorithm applied to $a$ and $c_n$ will find some such polynomial.

For the other direction, I have to be less concrete: suppose the first algorithm applied to $a$ and $c_n$ finds a $\Psi(x)$ such that $\Psi(c_n)=a$. The discussion of the second algorithm in the book implies that $\mathbb{Q}(c_i)=\mathbb{Q}(c_{i-1},b_i)$, which in turn implies that $\mathbb{Q}(c_n)=\mathbb{Q}(b_1,...,b_n)$, so every element of $\mathbb{Q}(c_n)$, including $c_n$, is a polynomial in $b_1,...,b_n$. Thus there is some $\Omega(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that $\Omega(b_1,...,b_n)=c_n$, $\Psi(\Omega(b_1,...,b_n))=a$, and we have that $a$ is a polynomial in $b_1,...,b_n$ iff the first algorithm finds that it is also a polynomial in $c_n$.